# How to get application type

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in Android development, and I wanted to know if it's possible to get the type of application installed on the Android's device (Games / Application, sorting like Google play).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get packagename, appname, icon, ...) from ApplicationInfo throuh Android SDK
but you can't get Google play infos

You can try out this unofficial [API](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) for Google Play infos

Comment: Thank I will dig in this direction, i think this is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "type of application" in Android. The concept of a "type" comes from a distribution channel, like the Play Store, Amazon AppStore for Android, BlackBerry World, etc. Not all apps come from a channel like this, and nothing is stored on the device regarding the channel's description, "type", etc.